# Beginner C++ Books on using Raspberry Pi

Tags: c++

There seems to be a shortage of books out there on using C++ with Raspberry Pi! I could literally only spot two, which I will paste below:

1. [https://www.amazon.com/Exploring-Raspberry-Pi-2-C/dp/1484217381#customerReviews](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1484217381)
2. [https://www.amazon.com/Learn-Program-Using-Raspberry-introduction/dp/0995791813](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0995791813)

Does anyone know any other books at all? C++ books with Raspberry Pi seems to be such a thing of niche!

Comment: Why would someone need a special book about C++ programming on the Raspberry Pi? It's just a regular Linux box.

Comment: Well, there are books on C programming using Arduino with so many projects with the associated project codes. As a beginner in C++ I would like have access to source code for projects using the Raspberry Pi! Would be of great help and support!

Comment: The difference is the Arduino is a microcontroller with a very special OS. For the Raspberry, you can use any book on Linux programming. All Linux boxes are the same, that's the idea of having Linux on the Raspberry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the [MagPi](https://www.raspberrypi.org/magpi/issues/) for some inspiration and plenty of tutorials. It is really worth a look! They have a series about C++ on the Pi too.

Other than that generic books on C++ will take you a long way as most things to learn about the language are not specific to the Pi. Once you're done learning the basic and more advanced concepts of C++ this way tutorials for the Pi, e.g. from the MagPi, will give more insight on the issues that are specific to the Pi, say the GPIO interface.

Comment: Great tip! Cheers will do. At the moment I am just learning C++ of a book. Once I finish learning the core language I will hit up both Arduinos and Raspberry Pis!